# diglossia vs. register

Tags: sociolinguistics

How does Diglossia differ from Register? This author never defines or mentions "register", nor [this Bristol University website on British Sign Language](http://www.bris.ac.uk/Depts/DeafStudiesTeaching/bslsoc/Sessions/s3.htm) or [Reddit](https://redd.it/gjuqmg).

> ### 2.3 Diglossia

> **Diglossia** is a sociolinguistic situation in which two very different varieties of a language
> are both used in a society, but in different situations. Typically, one is used in
> more formal or literary situations such as formal writing, university lectures, and news
> broadcasts, and is learned and encouraged in school. The other is used in conversation,
> informal television situations, folk literature, etc., and is preferred at home.
>       In the German-speaking areas of Switzerland, both Standard German and local
> varieties of German known as Swiss German are used; they are different enough
> from each other not to be mutually intelligible. Writing is almost always done
> in Standard German. Standard German is also used for formal speaking situations.
> Ordinary conversation, however, is normally in Swiss German. For example, a
> university course uses a textbook in Standard German, and lectures are given in
> Standard German; discussion after class between the professor and students, however,
> would be in Swiss German.
>       Arabic is another example of a language with diglossia. We have mentioned in the
> previous chapter that an Arabic speaker normally uses one dialect for speaking and
> another for writing. Modern Greek and the Dravidian languages also show diglossia.
>       The term 'diglossia' is usually reserved for quite distinct versions of the same
> language. However, other related variations occur. In English, there is not a sharp
> division between written and spoken English. *I forgot to put on my watch this
> morning* seems to be appropriate in any style of discourse, written or spoken. However,
> words such as *lest, pursuant, or vouchsafe* are much more likely to be found in
> written English, or in English read aloud from a written text. Forms such as *isn't,
> aren't, would've* are normal, almost required, in spoken English. In written English,
> they are regularly written as two words.

Henry Rogers, *Writing Systems* (2004), p 17.

Comment: I think the key is in "The term 'diglossia' is usually reserved for quite distinct versions of the same language.". So while Swiss German/Standard German will be diglossia, Common Czech/Standard Czech (e.g.) will not even though code switching still happens.

Comment: _Register_ is the name of the phenomenon, and it has many levels. The way you ask your roommate to pass the salt is not the same as the way you ask your grandmother at a family holiday. Everybody has dozens of "levels" that they use with different groups or in different contexts; those are register variants. _Diglossia_, on the other hand, refers specifically to situations where there are **two** variants, each more or less independent of the other, like Modern Greek, with Dimotiki and Katharevousa. A limiting case would appear to be Javanese, with three distinct levels subdivided further.

Comment: ... and then there are Australian languages, which appear always to have some diglossia, of one kind or another.